# xpath element identification -- Cleaner Xpath

Tags: java, html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I was able to identify the element using the actual xpath copied from the code directly, however can someone help me write a simpler xpath using the following code? The following code is a working code!

```
WebElement oCheckbox = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/label/div/i"));
WebElement oCheckbox1 = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/label/div/i"));
oCheckbox.click();
oCheckbox1.click();
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<body class="">
<div id="app">
<section class="bottom-padding cf top-padding white-bg">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 push-lg-9 padding-l-r-30 padding-bottom">
<div class="col-lg-9 pull-lg-3 padding-l-r-15">
<div class="row dropshadow">
<div class="col-lg-5 padding-none">
<div class="left-round fixed-height gray-bg">
<div>
<div class="section-title">
<div class="floatThead-wrapper" style="position: relative; clear: both;">
<div class="floatThead-container" style="overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1001; will-change: transform; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px); left: 0px; width: 410.867px;" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table class="table protocol-table" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 410.867px;">
<colgroup>
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<input id="select-pcsl-9777-protocol" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="select-pcsl-9777-protocol">
<div>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"/>
</div>
<span class="sr-only">Select</span>
</label>
```

Comment: you can use JavascriptExecutor ,

Comment: Is that id for the input generated dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
myDriver.findElement.ById("select-pcsl-9777-protocol")
```

Comment: Thank you, tried it.. Element not found error... I am even giving this explicit wait


WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(myDriver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='select-pcsl-9778-protocol']")));

Comment: The click does not happen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why @peter solution not work but you can use **JavascriptExecutor**

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("select-pcsl-9777-protocol"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

You can also use xpath

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='select-pcsl-9777-protocol']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: This is useful too, you guys are the best, I will explore all the options provided and see which one is best for me!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned both the following `xpath` are working but those are absolute paths:

```
WebElement oCheckbox = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/label/div/i"));
WebElement oCheckbox1 = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/label/div/i"));
```

Here is the equivalent logical `xpath`:

```
WebElement oCheckbox = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-check']"));
```

Incase you are trying to click on the `Select` element, you can get a bit granular as:

```
WebElement oCheckbox1 = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-check']/span[@class='sr-only']"));
```

But, I am a bit doubtful with the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute, so a garunteed `xpath` would be:

```
WebElement oCheckbox2 = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='select-pcsl-9777-protocol']//following::span[1]))"));
```

Comment: Thank you Debanjan, the logical xpath worked, I used it initially but then found out that the class is the same for all the check boxes on the page.

<input type="checkbox" id="select-pcsl-9777-protocol">, I have given the code in 2 parts:

Comment: This is how the code looks...

 <input id="select-pcsl-9777-protocol" type="checkbox"/>
 <label for="select-pcsl-9777-protocol">
 <div>
 <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"/>
 </div>
 <span class="sr-only">Select</span>
 </label>
 </div>
 </td>
 <td>
 <td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <div>
 <input id="select-pcsl-9778-protocol" type="checkbox"/>
 <label for="select-pcsl-9778-protocol">
 <div>
 <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"/>
 </div>
 <span class="sr-only">Select</span>
 </label>
 </div>
 </td>